# mkdir within a loop

Tags: python, mkdir

I am trying to create multiple directories on Python, one for each of the elements of the list loadcase_id_full defined simply by : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

I tried the following:

```
import os
import yaml
from pathlib import Path
this_dir = Path(__file__).parent

top_dir = this_dir.parent

base_dir = top_dir / 'tmp'
with open(path_to_acc_matrix) as f:
    var = yaml.safe_load(f)

# Extracting the data in lists of a size equal to the number of load cases (usually 5)
loadcase_id_full = var['acceleration_matrix'][4]
path_to_new_dirs = top_dir / 'templates' / 'tests' / 'data'

path_iter = 1
path_iter = str(path_iter)
pathname = 'QS-' + path_iter
directory = path_to_new_dirs / pathname

for index in loadcase_id_full :
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    path_iter = index
    path_iter = str(path_iter)
    pathname = 'QS-' + path_iter
    directory = base_dir / pathname

    print(directory)
```

This only creates the first directory (so from the "directory" variable defined outside of the loop...)
The print function shows me that the paths I want are correct:

```
/users/develop/tmp/QS-1
/users/develop/tmp/QS-2
/users/develop/tmp/QS-3
/users/develop/tmp/QS-4
/users/develop/tmp/QS-5
```

But it just doesn't create them. If I put the os.mkdirs at the end of the loop, it doesn't create any directories. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: What exactly version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: What additional information would you need?

Comment: What is `base_dir`?

Comment: Daweo has an interesting point: perhaps the `os` module is not fully compatible with `pathlib` in Python 3.6. Consider using `Path.mkdir` instead, and avoiding `os` altogether.

Comment: os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True) doesn't solve it....

Comment: I am already struggling with the first line... are you using `/` for string concatenation?

Comment: I didn't say exist_ok solves it: I said you can avoid the if-statement that way.

Comment: @Rafael-WO That's a feature of pathlib

Comment: For starters, `import os` and `from pathlib import Path; top_dir = Path('something')` are missing. And some variables are undefined.

Comment: I'll edit the post to show everything

Comment: Yes, but without a complete example that we can't run, we have to guess. If we guess incorrectly, we don't reproduce your problem. More importantly, *you* should run the exact code you post here as well, to make sure it actually includes your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to create two sets of `directory`? One in one path `paths_to_new_dirs` and another with `base_dir` as parent?

Comment: Why are you setting all the variables in the loop *after* you make the directory?

Comment: @Barmar It certainly is overdone. A single line of `directory = base_dir / f'QS-{index}'` is enough.

Comment: Because that's what this guy advised:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528324/how-can-i-create-multiple-directories-using-a-loop-in-python

Comment: My concern exactly @Barmar. Because this will only create all but the last one (in the for loop) if it was to run correctly.

Comment: Your code is now not a self-contained example, since it reads from a file that we don't access to. Make it minimal: include the value of `loadcase_id_full`, not show how it's read and assigned.

Comment: @elle.delle That's using a `while` loop, not `for` loop. And it's a stupid way to do it there, too.

Comment: Goes to show that copy-paste StackOverflow is not a good idea.

Comment: You still don't show how `base_dir` is defined.

Comment: You're creating the first directory in `path_to_new_dirs` the rest of them are in `base_dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of the code that hopefully avoids confusion and gets to the need of creating multiple directories.

```
from pathlib import Path


top_dir = Path('ENTER YOUR DATA PATH HERE')
base_dir = Path('ENTER YOUR BASE PATH HERE')
loadcase_id_full = ['ENTER YOUR LIST VALUES HERE', '...']

path_to_new_dirs = top_dir / 'templates' / 'tests' / 'data'
path_to_new_dirs.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

for index in loadcase_id_full:
    directory = base_dir / f'QS-{index}'
    print(directory)
    directory.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
```

Comment: The problem stem from the fact that `base_dir / "tmp"` did not exists. Your base_dir did. This is why I asked if your parent pathS exist. Glad that was the culprit. If you could accept this as the answer to your OP, that would be great.